# Schmidt Decomposition of a Matrix

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $H,K$ be Hilbert spaces. Let $T \in B(H,K)$. By Schmidt Theorem, we know that there exists countable collections of orthonormal vectors $(\phi_n)_n$ and $ (\psi_n)_n$ such that $T(x) = \sum_n s_n(T) \langle \phi_n|x \rangle \psi_n$.

Let $T=
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 1  \\
    0 & 0  \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$.

I'm trying to write the Schmidt Decomposition of $T$.

I found that we have eigenvalues $\lambda_1=2$, $\lambda_2=0$, and eigenvectors $v_1 = (1,1)$ and $v_2= (-1,1)$.

From here, I'm not sure how to find the orthonormal vectors.

I'm very new to this. I wonder if someone could walk me through the steps.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the Schmidt decomposition is essentially the same as SVD with $s_n$ being the singular values (not eigenvalues of $T$), and $\psi_n$, $\phi_n$ being the orthonormal columns of $U,V$ (not the eigenvectors of $T$).

In this case $$T=UDV^*=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\sqrt2&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\-1&1\end{pmatrix}$$

The $s_n$ are $\sqrt2$ and $0$, while $\phi_1=v_1=(1,1)/\sqrt2$, $\phi_2=v_2=(-1,1)/\sqrt2$, $\psi_1=e_1=(1,0)$, $\psi_2=e_2=(0,1)$.

So \begin{align}Tx=UDV^*x&=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\begin{pmatrix}\sqrt2&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\-1&1\end{pmatrix}x=\begin{pmatrix}\sqrt2&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\langle v_1,x\rangle\\\langle v_2,x\rangle\end{pmatrix}\\
&=\sqrt2\langle v_1,x\rangle e_1+0\langle v_2,x\rangle e_2\end{align}